# having issue in login form?

Tags: php, authentication

i am new in php and i am on learning phases, i created a register table in database and want to simple login by using register table data.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $login = "SELECT FROM register WHERE name='".$name."' AND email= '".$email."'  ";
    $run = mysqli_query( $con, $login );
    if ( mysqli_num_rows($run)>0 ) {
        echo "<script>alert('Logged In Successfully'); </script>";
    }

    exit();
}
```

Comment: what's the question for us?

Comment: Ask a question.

Comment: my code is not working, i am getting result from register database table but mysqli_num_rows is not working

Comment: @AmeliaSmith do you have any records in the register table ? What is the output of `SELECT count(*) FROM register`

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: yes i have record in register table and it and getting record but not login .

Comment: enable `display_errors` and you see a warning from `mysqli_query`. Query has a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like Because you did not specify which data type you want to get from database

```
$login = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM register WHERE name='".$name."' AND email= '".$email."'  ";
```

and then your code may change like

```
 if ( $run > 0 ) {
        echo "<script>alert('Logged In Successfully'); </script>";
    }
```

Comment: you're half right, `$run` in this case is still a resource tho. can you add the missing step, and explain what what OP did wrong?

Comment: yes it is a resource but in that code he should use that resource in my opinion. He wanted to query some datas. But he did not specified which datas he get. If he change the query that i describe above, he can check count of email and name patterns